# dmesg -T results in inconsistent timestamp

Tags: linux, timestamp

This question is **not** related to the pause/resume issue!

For the same event 'dmesg' shows always the same time stamp, e.g.

```
[31765279.760248]
```

However when using 'dmesg -T', for the same event it shows slightly different seconds count, e.g. calling `dmesg -T | grep something | tail -1` twice results in:

```
[Thu Jan 29 01:12:39 2015] event details...
[Thu Jan 29 01:12:38 2015] event details...
```

I need to compare events with history and act on new events. However this difference makes it impossible to use a simple string compare.

As a work around I clip the seconds from the strings before I compare them. I can do it in this case since the events I filter do not happen more than once in 5 minutes.

Does anyone know why this inaccuracy happens?

```
uname -a => Linux (hostname) 3.5.0-45-generic #68~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 4 16:18:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I have no explanation for the inconsistency you're seeing, but allow me a silly question: why don't you do the comparison on the raw-value and convert it to human readable manually later if needed?

Comment: I'm lazy :) I know there are several workarounds and I'm using one, but I'm curious to know the reason. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

Those timestamps are converted to real time by adding them to the system boot time. If the system came up at 1491516481.480856282 and you add a fractional offset to it, sometimes you'll see one extra full second.

Haven't checked the code but pretty certain that's the reason. There's a bit more information in [Convert dmesg timestamp to custom date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890789/convert-dmesg-timestamp-to-custom-date-format/36361197#36361197) including a response I wrote.