# Have dmesg print human readable time

Tags: linux, logging, linux-kernel, timestamp, dmesg

I would like dmesg to print human readable date times without passing the -T parameter. Is there a way to do this without setting up an alias? In config files maybe?

dmesg output:

```
# dmesg | tail -1
[    6.639729] IPv6: enp03: link becomes ready
```

in this case I would like dmesg to print:

```
# dmesg | tail -1
[Fri Sep 15 08:15:29 2017] IPv6: enp03: link becomes ready
```

Comment: You could define some `bash` function or some shell script (and pay attention to `$PATH`)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890789/convert-dmesg-timestamp-to-custom-date-format) may provide you with relevant answers

Comment: Why is an alias not enough in this case?

Comment: @rogerdpack I honestly can't remember

Answer (score 7):

> I would like dmesg to print human readable date times without passing
>   the -T parameter. Is there a way to do this without setting up an
>   alias?

If you don't want an alias, which would usually be the best choice, you could place a script in a directory which is in `PATH` before `/bin` (if the real `dmesg` is `/bin/dmesg`), e. g. `~/bin/dmesg`:

```
exec /bin/dmesg -T "$@"
```

Don't forget to `chmod +x`.